# Mess table in GridView and run time error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, database-design

I want to create a table as below to interact with database to retrieve, delete, update data.

My output in design view is very messy. And when i try to run the page i receive the following error:

> Control 'GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Please advise me for enhancement based on below data table and my coding.

[image: User interface for table, label and button]

.aspx:

```
<div class="modal-bg">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableEventValidation="false" 
BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
CellPadding="4" Width="426px">
<Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField>
              <HeaderTemplate>
              UsernameLast Login  Status
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>                     
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                Active Role
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ActiveRole") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderTemplate >
                Full name
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                Email Address
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                Last Login  Status
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Last Login  Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<button id="newuserbutton" onclick="return newuserbutton_onclick()">
        Create New User</button>
```

Thank you for helps.

Comment: In ASPNet webforms - everything needs to run within a form tag. The runat="server" attribute indicates that the form should be processed on the server. It also indicates that the enclosed controls can be accessed by server scripts:

Comment: does anyone have any idea on how to create this table?

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually try to place your control inside  the `<form runat="server"></form>` tags?

Comment: yes my problem was that gridview is not in form tags. how about the table? it is not proper by the way i use item template.

Comment: which table do you mean? What is wrong with the table?

Comment: I am supposed to create the table above called User Management. But according to my coding, my table is messed up, not as i want.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your html code with  tag => `<form runat="server"> ... </form>`